# Does neutron decay have an additional factor of 2 in the decay rate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

In neutron decay, a down quark decays into an up quark. Does the fact that there are two down quarks with the possibility of decaying contribute a factor of 2 to the decay rate?

My confusion is that the two down quarks are in the *initial* state rather than the final state, whereas the density of states always considers the final state. However, my logic is that you can consider the neutron decaying into a proton where *this* down quark remains, and another where *that* down quark remains, and so the density of states is doubled.

Is this correct? I cannot find a discussion of it anywhere.

Comment: *Additional* factor  compared to what?

Comment: The usual density of states due to momentum?

Comment: The initial state is "fixed", and the decaying quarks are all taken into consideration in the "dressed" matrix element, converting a unique static neutron to a moving proton of variable momentum. So the matrix element contains all that quarks-in-hadron fuzz. Most decent texts calculating the rate will remind you of that.